# Less Frequent Words appearing bigger - WordCloud in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, nlp, word-cloud

I have been plotting the `wordcloud` using the `wordcloud` package from Python. Here's a sample of the code:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)

def show_wordcloud(data, title = None):
    wordcloud = WordCloud(
        background_color='black',
        stopwords=stopwords,
        max_words=200,
        max_font_size=40, 
        scale=3,
        random_state=1 # chosen at random by flipping a coin; it was heads
).generate(str(data))

    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(15, 15))
    plt.axis('off')
    if title: 
        fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=20)
        fig.subplots_adjust(top=2.3)
    matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})
    plt.title('Most Used Words for Emotion Tag 2 (What is the highlight?)')    
    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.savefig('2.jpg')
    plt.show()

show_wordcloud(df2['words'])
```

[image]

Now, what I understood from  the official documentation of Wordcloud is that, most frequent non-stop words appear to be bigger, but here chirping is appearing than Bengal. But then when I check out the frequency of chirping:

```
In [20]: df2[df2['words'].str.contains("Chirping")]
Out[20]:    words             tagid
           Chirping of birds    2
           Chirping of birds    2
```

And now, when I check the frequency of Bengal:

```
In [21]: df2[df2['words'].str.contains("Bengal")]
Out[21]:     words                 tagid
        The mighty Bay Of Bengal    2
        Royal Bengal Tigers       2
        #NammaBengaluru             2
        Traditional Bengali Meal    2
        Royal Bengal Tiger          2
        Enterning Taj Bengal.       2
```

"Bengal" is appearing small in "yellow" color just below the word "Part" left of "Trekking".
Now I'm not able to understand why is that happening, or how I can fix that. Also I want to know is there a way to remove prepositions from `wordcloud`, like at, beside, inside, etc.

Is there a way I can assign weightage or frequency and then plot the `wordcloud`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post a sample output of the 'data' variable? It might be possible that the entire text while passing it to the canvas object.

You can assign weightage based on the frequency of the words in a text using `getFrequencyDictForText()` API to get the frequency of the text and `makeImage()` to generate the canvas.

Please refer to the API documentation here: https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/auto_examples/frequency.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-frequency-py

Comment: I didn't understand, may I know what do you mean by sample output?

Comment: I meant the print output of the 'data' variable @DebadriDutta

Comment: @SoumithriChilakamarri You have comments on SO to ask for clarification and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Answers are, well, for answering the question.

Comment: data is just an argument of the function, here data is basicaly, df2['words']. that'll be a dataframe column, so it won't be of much help

Comment: Refer to this link here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generating-word-cloud-python/ . I would suggest you to set the same parameters in the `WordCloud()` API as present in the link above. If it's still not working, I can assist you if you can share a google colab notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Frequencies are saved in the `word_` property of the `WordCloud` type. It is saved in a dictionary type as below:

```
{
 'word1': 1.00,
 'word2': 0.980093876357,
 'word3': 0.978478648733,
 ...
}
```

So, play with it. The function below inverts the values, making the least frequent being the highest.

```
def invert_wc(wc):
    keys = list(wc.words_.keys())
    values = list(wc.words_.values())
    values.reverse()
    wc.words_ = dict(zip(keys, values))
    return wc
```

Then, just generate it with:

```
wc.generate_from_frequencies(wc.words_)
```

This is not a silver bullet and must be analyzed for each case.